# count how many times keys repeat between dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I check to see how many times the keys in one `dict1` exist in `dict2`. If the keys of `dict1` exist in `dict2` a variable, `val`, with an initial value of `4` should be subtracted based on how many times the keys are found.

For example `dict1` looks like this

```
print dict1
{(2, 0): 3, (3, 1): 0, (1, 1): 2, (2, 2): 1}
```

and `dict2` looks like this

```
print `dict2`
{(2, 0): 323, (3, 1): 32, (10, 10): 21, (20, 2): 100}
```

Since there are two repeat keys between the dicts,`val` should be equal to `2`.

if `dict2` looks identical to `dict1`, then `val` should be `0`.

Also, `dict1` will always be the same size, but `dict2` can get quite large, so a fast lookup method would be ideal. Lastly, the values of dicts here don't really mean anything.

Comment: `len([k for k in dict1 if k in dict2])`

Comment: @alfasin Why build a list just to get its length? `sum(1 for k in dict1 if k in dict2)` is more efficient. However, for this task set intersection is faster.

Comment: @PM2Ring ha, good point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using set intersection:

```
d1 = {(2, 0): 3, (3, 1): 0, (1, 1): 2, (2, 2): 1} 
d2 = {(2, 0): 323, (3, 1): 32, (10, 10): 21, (20, 2): 100} 

sd1 = set(d1.keys())
sd2 = set(d2.keys())
len(sd1.intersection(sd2))
```

Edit:
Because key views are already set-like, so you can do `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` directly. Note that `.keys()` is a very cheap call because it simply provides an alternative interface to the existing dict structure (Credits to @PM2RING in the comments).

Comment: key views are already set-like, so you can do `d1.keys() & d2.keys() `

Comment: Note that `.keys()` is a very cheap call because it just provides an alternative interface to the existing dict structure.

Answer (score 4):

Since dict_keys are [already set-like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), you can simply use

```
len(dict1.keys() & dict2.keys())
```

That is for Python 3. In Python 2, the equivalent view object is [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which you'd use similarly.

```
len(dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sets out of the list of keys in each dict.
Find the intersection and union of those sets.
`union - intersection` gives you the set of differences.
If that's 0, then you return 0;
otherwise, return the size of the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Python 2 and 3: `len(set(dict1).intersection(dict2))`

```
In [1]: dict1 = {(2, 0): 3, (3, 1): 0, (1, 1): 2, (2, 2): 1}

In [2]: dict2 = {(2, 0): 323, (3, 1): 32, (10, 10): 21, (20, 2): 100}

In [3]: len(set(dict1).intersection(dict2))
Out[3]: 2
```